# Use of mwrank to calculate rank of an elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, sagemath

I am new to the concept of the elliptic curve. I was going through an article, where the author claimed to have calculated the rank of a family of an elliptic curve using $mwrank.$ The family of the elliptic curve he took is given by $E_{k} : y^2 = (F_{2k}x+1)(F_{2k+2}x+1)(F_{2k+4}x+1),$ where $F_{k}$ is the $kth$ fibonacci number defined by $F_{k} = F_{k-1}+F_{k-2}$ for $k > 1$ with $F_{0} = 0$ and $F_{1} = 1.$
I tried doing the same using SageMath, after a while, it becomes slow as the magnitude of coefficients grows. I searched for the methodology of using $mwrank,$ but did not found.
I want to know how to use this software or package known as $mwrank.$

Comment: I'm in interested in elliptic curves too, but unfortunately I'm new to the concept too.  Could you show some of the code you tried?

Comment: I'm going to close this as not being about mathematics. But I'll also note a few things. One can use mwrank from sage, as it's packaged with sage. See for example https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/interfaces/sage/interfaces/mwrank.html. Various algorithms in sage default to mwrank behind the scenes (such as EllipticCurve.rank()). It is also possible to use mwrank through eclib (available at https://github.com/JohnCremona/eclib). There are some docs there. If you have trouble, send an email to either the sage-users, sage-support, or John Cremona (though he follows the sage lists too).